# RxJS: Observable.webSocket() get access to onopen, onclose…

Tags: javascript, websocket, rxjs, rxjs5

```
const ws = Observable.webSocket('ws://…');
ws.subscribe(
  message => console.log(message),
  error => console.log(error),
  () => {},
);
```

I want to observe my WebSocket connection with RxJS. Reacting to `onmessage` events by subscribing to the observable works like a charm. But how can I access the `onopen` event of the WebSocket? And is it possible to trigger the WebSocket `.close()` method? RxJS is pretty new to me and I did research for hours, but maybe I just don't know the right terms. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [sourcecode of the Websocket](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.ts#L181) there is a config object `WebSocketSubjectConfig` which contains observables which you can link to different events. You should be able to pass a `NextObserver` typed object to config value `openObserver` like so:

```
const openEvents = new Subject<Event>();
const ws = Observable.webSocket({
  url: 'ws://…', 
  openObserver: openEvents 
});

openEvents
  .do(evt => console.log('got open event: ' + evt))
  .merge(ws.do(msg => console.log('got message: ' + msg))
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation made some things more clear for me.

Answer (score 5):

The link of @Mark van Straten to the file is dead. The updated link is [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.ts). I also wanted to highlight the usage as suggested in the docs. A in my opinion better copy and paste solution to play around with:

```
import { webSocket } from "rxjs/webSocket";

webSocket({
  url: "wss://echo.websocket.org",
  openObserver: {
    next: () => {
      console.log("connection ok");
    },
  },
  closeObserver: {
    next(closeEvent) {
      // ...
    }
  },
}).subscribe();
```